# SWT vs AWT in image file process performance?

Tags: java, performance, image-processing, swt, awt

In server side image process, should I use AWT or SWT?

I think AWT maybe too abstract away from the actual image data bits, so I guess SWT maybe slightly faster.

Or do you suggest another open source image process library? (BSD or Apache licensed)

The server is running Ubuntu 11.04.

Requirements:

- Read/write image from/to stream instead of files.
- The image type is given as parameter rather then guess from extension.
  (This is optional if it can determine the image type from the header bytes.)
- Support of JPG, PNG, GIF.
- (Bonus) Support of Animated GIF.

Use cases:

- Generate thumbnails.
- Add some banner texts.
- Add cryptic image watermark and validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWT has very little in terms of image processing. The standard JDK image stuff has the fancy ImageIO package, and Java2D which can do pretty much *everything.* I'd call this a no-brainer: use Java's built-in stuff, and don't try to use SWT for something it's not intended for.

Answer (score 2):

I can second Ernest's notion about SWT for this task, forget it.

But while Swing is fine for image manipulation and output, Swing's `ImageIO` fails too often during input: many images which you'll meet in the wild, and which work fine in the browser, produce Exceptions.

The best Java option I know of is JAI, which unfortunately is a pain to use. So do yourself a favor, and use JAI for input, and Swing for the rest, like this:

```
     RenderedImage renderedImage = JAI.create("fileload", imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
     RenderedImageAdapter planarImage = new RenderedImageAdapter(renderedImage);
     BufferedImage image planarImage.getAsBufferedImage();
```

JAI will also fail in rare cases (JPGs with custom color space, as written by Photoshop, are an example). If you want to do even better, use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), which is an ultra-powerful command line tool. There are Java interfaces available, which either provide an API for the command line, or use JNI to call the native library, see [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php).